# Node.js - Load previous messages when user connects? bit confused with logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I am making a chat application on Node.js and Socket.io
I am a bit confused about logic here, I am still new.

How would I go about making it so when user connects to chat, it loads previous messages in chat room? (I already made it so they are logged and stored in db).

I mean how do I make it so it loads previous messages only for that specific user rather than whole chatroom gets messages refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Rooms and Namespaces](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

To answer your specific question:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('previousMessages', allMessages);
});
```

The parameter "socket" refers to the newly connected socket, "io" broadcasts to all clients.